# how to conceal filename and line number in quickfix window

Tags: conceal

**Context**

Say in vim, after `:grep text *`, then `:copen`, then cursor in a quickfix window, which has contents like below

```
some-very-very-very-long-path/file1.txt|1 col 46| some text
some-very-very-very-long-path/file2.txt|84 col 34| another text
some-very-very-very-long-path/file3.txt|243 col 29| yetanother text
```

**Problem**

How to conceal the filename and line column number at the beginning of each line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `conceal` feature for this.

Add the following to the file `~/.vim/after/syntax/qf.vim` (first creating the file if necessary):

```
syntax match ConcealedDetails /\v^[^|]*\|[^|]*\| / conceal
setlocal conceallevel=2
setlocal concealcursor=nvic
```

The first line sets up a syntax item to conceal anything that matches the regular expression.

The second line informs Vim that you want to hide any concealed items that don't have a replacement `cchar` set.

The third line makes it so that the text is *always* concealed, whatever mode you are in.

The regular expression I used presumes that your file names/paths won't ever contain a `|` character. If they do, you'll need to adjust your regular expression to account for this.

Further details:

- [`:help conceal`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#conceal)
- [`:help 'conceallevel'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27conceallevel%27)
- [`:help 'concealcursor'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27concealcursor%27)

Comment: This works but syntax highlighting in the qf buffer breaks. (i.e. filename part is no longer shown in different color). Any way to fix it?

Comment: nvm. not an issue if concealing entire path and line numbers. Added answer below to hide a prefix of the path. https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/42868

Answer (score 4):

While the other answers here have all the necessary pointers ever needed, I think there is lacking a comprehensive solution IMHO.

Below is a ready-to-paste in your `.vimrc` (or equivalent)

```
au BufReadPost quickfix :call ConcealPath() 

function ConcealPath()
       syntax match ConcealedPath /\v^\/[^|]*\// conceal cchar=&
       setlocal conceallevel=2
       setlocal concealcursor=nvic
       setlocal nowrap 
endfunction

function UnconcealPath()
       setlocal conceallevel=0
       setlocal wrap
endfunction
```

More than being a comprehensive answer, it is a more general solution.

You are now equipped to hide similar "long paths" without any file-edits, any where in vim (not just in a `quickfix` window), using

`:call ConcealPath()`

and revert/unhide using

`:call UnconcealPath()`

**NOTE-1**: The use of `set wrap` and `set nowrap` is only for aesthetics that I liked in my usage

**NOTE-2**: You can also conveniently map your favourite keys to reduce typing in case you need frequently using the function calls

**NOTE-3**: All this works only when you notice `+conceal` is present in your `:version` (or `vim --version` from terminal). So `-conceal` will knock you off this deal. Neovim (`nvim`) on the other hand, will not suffer from this issue due to its philosophy of *all-possible features always-on*.

Comment: Thanks for the summary! A small nitpick that you don't need the `:`s inside autocmd and functions, only when using Ex commands interactively... So personally I'd recommend removing those.

Comment: @filbranden Done!

Comment: I updated my answer to include complete instructions. Not sure why I didn't do so in the first place, as it's actually more concise this way, so thanks for nudging me into doing so! I like your idea of adding functions so you can toggle the behaviour. +1

Answer (score 0):

according to quickfix.txt and the answer by Rich, following works:

```
au BufReadPost quickfix  setlocal modifiable
            \ | silent exe 'g/^/s/\v^[^|]*\|[^|]*\| //'
            \ | setlocal nomodifiable
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I'm not sure this uses conceal so much as actually removing the relevant characters?

Answer (score 0):

### Hiding a known common prefix of the long path

```
syn match qfFileName "^[^|]*" nextgroup=qfSeparator contains=ConcealedDetails
syntax match ConcealedDetails /^.*my_projects_path/ conceal cchar=↭ contained

setlocal conceallevel=2                                                        
setlocal concealcursor=nvic
```

`qfFileName` is defined in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/qf.vim`. We are redefining to add that it could contain our `ConecealedDetails` matchgroup. Without this, the whole line will not be highlighted.