What is the good errorformat or compiler plugin for pyright?
I'm using pyright for static checking. I do not use language servers and want to avoid that if I can.
I want to use quickfix with pyright and I'm wondering if there's an existing pyright compiler plugin that I am missing or alternatively what is the good errorformat that I can use for pyright.

I would have a ~/compiler/pyright.vim with the following content:
set makeprg=pyright
set errorformat=%f:%l:%c\ -\ %t%.%#:%m

You can switch using pyright running:
:compiler pyright

You can check the current file using:
:make %

You can check the list of error or warning using:
:cw


Thanks, this is very helpful. There's a minor problem that the filename and location for every error line in the quickfix window adds a noise and makes the output a bit hard to read - I was able to use the suggestion from https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/31334 somewhat adapted for this case to solve this however.
